# Filter ss process output without using grep

Tags: grep, netstat, iproute2, filter

`ss -p` can give the process name, process id (PID) and the file descriptor associated with the connection.

Example: `ss -tuanp`

```
[...]
tcp   ESTAB   0   0   x.x.x.x:59594   x.x.x.x:993   users:(("thunderbird",pid=1985,fd=98)) 
[...]
```

While the filter options of `ss` seem to be quite advanced, I haven't been able to find a way to filter the `users` JSON based data structure in order to get only the process name. Do you know whether this is possible without using grep/awk/sed/whatever?

The `ss` advanced documentation is not very meaningful and Alexey Kuznetosv, the ss' author is not very present on the internet. I'm asking this question in order to avoid reading `ss` source code.

Comment: Might be easier to use something like `lsof` for this.  It has some pretty robust filtering options and ability to select which fields are output.

Comment: Not entirely great by look at `lsof -itcp:993 -a -c thunderbird -F c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked into the source code of the `ss` and found, the `ss` doesn't support filtering by process name. It parses the `/proc` tree at run to show process names. So, there isn't a way to avoid of usage traditional tools like the `grep`.